# Is it safe to let cats tear up paper?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety

If a cat likes finding paper and tearing it apart, is it safe to let the cat do so? And does it matter for the type of paper, e.g. toilet paper,  tissue paper, wrapping paper, printer paper, etc.?

I'm not asking how to stop it, but if the cat enjoys doing this, can I just let it go?

Alternatively, is it a sign of a problem?

Comment: One question would be: does the cat eat it? Despite that, I would be careful with sharp edges and toxic ink. I do not see other risks (but I am not a cat person...)

Comment: Thank your lucky stars it is just paper. The cat is a kitten or still young I imagine. Once it gets bigger, it will start shredding all your curtains, carpets and upholstery. At that point you will wish the cat was just shredding paper. I put sheets of cardboard all over the house to keep my cat busy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If your cat is ONLY shredding the paper, that is fine.**

Some cats seem to like the feeling of destroying things, and paper is easy to destroy.  I would even take advantage of its desire to shred paper by providing it with things that it's allowed to shred, and encouraging it to shred those, such as cardboard scratchers.  If your cat is busy shredding and clawing those, it's a lot less likely to shred and claw your furniture and walls, and it's probably happy for being allowed to shred something.

**But be careful if your cat is eating paper.**

Accidentally eating a tiny piece now and then is normal for cats that shred paper, and not a concern because a tiny piece will probably pass through harmlessly.  But if the cat is drawn to eating paper, that is a big health concern.  Large amounts of paper will make the cat vomit, or can even get stuck in the digestive tract and cause a blockage that may even require surgery to remove.  Therefore, if you notice the cat intentionally eating paper, make sure to keep all paper away from it.